# Error when trying to get single item from element.all in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I have the following test code (a simplified example):

```
e = element(by.id('element-id'));

it('description', function(){
    e.all(by.tagName('my-directive')).then(function(items){
        expect(items.count()).toEqual(3); //error
        expect(items.length).toEqual(3); //ok
        expect(items.get(0).getAttribute('my-attr')).toEqual('1'); //error
    });
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="element-id">
    <my-directive my-attr="1"></my-directive>
    <my-directive my-attr="0"></my-directive>
    <my-directive my-attr="0"></my-directive>
</div>
```

When I run this test I get the following error:

TypeError: undefined is not a function

I stripped it down and found out that the error is from the get() function and the count() function. I have read about the functions in the Protractor API and used them the same way as the example on the site, so I don't understand why it does not work for me.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I have also tried this (included 'element'):

```
e.element.all(by.tagName('my-directive')).then(function(items){...})
```

But that gave an error event without the get() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`items` in this case is just an ordinary array. You get

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

because there isn't any function on the Array.prototype called `count`.

`count()` and `get()` can only be called on ElementFinderArrays, which is a Protractor specific object: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder

If you want to get the length and one of the elements' attribute, this will work:

```
e.all(by.tagName('my-directive')).then(function(items){
    expect(items.length).toEqual(3);
    expect(items[0].getAttribute('my-attr')).toEqual('1');
});
```

or like this:

```
expect(e.all(by.tagName('my-directive')).count()).toEqual(3);
expect(e.all(by.tagName('my-directive')).get(0).getAttribute('my-attr')).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: Btw, there are also `first()` and `last()` worth mentioning. Also, `get()` supports negative indexing.